# Functions as first class objects in SageMath

Tags: sage

How in SageMath to represent a function from a set `X` to a set `Y`?

I want to enumerate *all* functions from a set `X` to a set `Y`. How to represent the values of the iterator which enumerates them?

I know I can just make a Python hash, but maybe there is already a more suitable object in Sage? (which would be internally represented as a hash but work as a function when applied to an argument)